# Wit.ai conflict with Stories

Tags: node.js, wit.ai

Can anyone tell me why the mergeIntentOld and mergeIntentTeam bot executes clash in the following app?

https://wit.ai/cisnky/fb_weather/stories

Is it because both stories use wit/contact?

Should an app only have one story that deals with the entities?

Has anyone had much luck with apps that have multiple stories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entities needed to be set as trait and not keyword search.